# downloading gzip image in ios

Tags: ios, gzip, nsdata

I am downloading an image in iOS in the following format:

```
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Thu, 31 Oct 2013 19:08:58 GMT";
    Expires = "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    "Set-Cookie" = "JSESSIONID=1mrh644zbpgutn1xk116n825u;Path=/";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
```

I am trying to use this: https://github.com/st3fan/cocoa-utils/blob/master/src/NSDataGZipAdditions.m to do the unarchiving... but it does not seem to be working.

Here is my current, unworking code:

```
NSString *authHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OAuth %@", credentials.accessToken];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myURL];
    [request addValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue new] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
        if (err) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);
        }
        //here create file from _data_

        NSData *mydata = [NSData dataWithCompressedData:data];
        self.propImg1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:mydata];
        [self.propImg1 setNeedsLayout];
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Your content-type appears to be "text/html" -- are you *sure* it's an image you're downloading? Is it perhaps actually an image that's embedded in an HTML page?

Comment: Define "it does not seem to be working". What happens exactly?

Comment: I receive the log statement inflate: ret != Z_OK -3 which is happening in the NSDataGZipAdditions.m file, resulting in nil being returned

Comment: if I open the link in a browser, the image is displayed and I am not able to view the HTML source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'd suggest checking out the response's `statusCode` and make sure it's `200`.
2. You say your server reported a [`Content-Encoding`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11) of

   ```
   "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
   ```

   that doesn't mean your `NSData` is gzip data. I believe that some web servers can transparently gzip their responses, and iOS transparently unzips that for you. You generally don't have to use a gzip library to unzip for most web server requests.

   This is evidenced by your [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) would suggest the response wasn't an image:

   ```
   "Content-Type" = "text/html";
   ```

   Admittedly, we should hesitate to draw too many conclusions from the `Content-Type` (because some custom web services are sloppy about setting that), but it is not consistent with your assertion that the resulting `NSData` is gzip data.

   You've added a comment below, showing us the `NSData`, and that is, in fact, a string script. It looks like it's probably HTML, not an image.
3. I'd `NSLog` the `data` (or set a breakpoint inside this block and issue the `po data` command in the debugger) and see what it looks like, and eliminate the ambiguity here. If it's largely hex values between `20` and `7f` (plus the occasional `0a` and possibly even a `0d`), that suggests that the response is a string, which you could then log it as a string.

   Perhaps you can update your question with the first few lines of the `data` hex dump, and we can help you diagnose what's going on (as you can often look at the first few bytes and confirm if it's text, a gzip, or an image).

   Or, now that you've confirmed it's a string response (that looks like it might be HTML), you should convert it to a `NSString` and log it, and you'll see what's going on.
4. By the way, when you fix your request issue, since you're doing UI update in your completion block, either use `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` for your completion block, or make sure to dispatch the UI update back to the main queue (as I've done in my example below).

Thus:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue new] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);
    }

    NSInteger statusCode = -1;
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
    }

    NSLog(@"statusCode = %d", statusCode); // this should be 200
    NSLog(@"data = %@", data);             // if really text, you'll largely see values b/w 20 and 7f and the occasional 0a

    // if it does look like largely 20-7f and a few 0a values, then try displaying it as a string:
    //
    // NSLog(@"data string = %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //here create file from _data_

    NSData *mydata = [NSData dataWithCompressedData:data];
    if (mydata) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:mydata];
        if (image) {
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                self.propImg1.image = image;
                [self.propImg1 setNeedsLayout];
            }];
        }
    }

    // ...
}];
```

Comment: the status code is 200 and the logged data is data = <0a0a0a3c 73637269 70743e0a 76617220 75726c20 3d207769 6e646f77 2e6c6f63 6174696f 6e2e7061 74686e61 6d65202b 2077696e 646f772e 6c6f6361 74696f6e 2e686173 683b0a69 66287769 6e646f77 2e6c6f63 6174696f 6e2e7365 61726368 20262620 77696e64 6f772e6c 6f636174 696f6e2e 73656172 63682e6c 656e6774 68203e20 31297b0a 20202020 75726c20 2b3d2077 696e646f 772e6c6f 63617469 6f6e2e73 65617263 683b202f 2f202331 38393631 370a7d0a 0a0a0a76 6172206c 6f63203d 20276874 7470733a 2f2f7465 73742e73 616c6573 666f7263 652e636f 6d2f3f65 633d3330 32267374 ....

Comment: @TylerHarrington Yep, that's a text string, not a gzip file. Do the conversion to NSString (as shown in that commented code) and you'll see what I mean. It reports `<script>
var url = window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;
if(window.location.search && window.location.search.length > 1){
    url += window.location.search; // #189617
}



var loc = 'https://test.salesforce.com/?ec=302&st...`

Comment: @TylerHarrington if you convert the whole `NSData` to a `NSString` and look at that it might provide insights about the problem. But likely the request was not well-formed or the URL is wrong. But you're getting HTML (or some script) back, not an image.

Comment: yep, i think the script is what renders the image for a download... i need to figure out what the loc variable ends up being because that is what prompts me to download the image in the browser.

Comment: it is simply an image

Comment: I think I ultimately need to get the value of location... which I am unsure if that's possible. Where in chat can I message you?

Comment: @TylerHarrington Feel free to join me in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40537/downloading-gzip-image-in-ios